# No Mono release for Debian 11 stable-bullseye

Tags: mono, debian

I am trying to install `mono-complete` on my Debian 11 VPS. However it seems that there is no release for debian:

```
E: The repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-bullseye Release' does not have a Release file.
```

There does seem to be a release for Ubuntu, but that has a dependency which has a dependency that has no installation candidate.

What is the correct way to install Mono on Debian 11? I have scoured the internet but everything seems to show the exact same method, which does not work.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/ Ask yourself why you wanted an obsolete thing.

Comment: Did you try the procedure listed here:
https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-mono-on-debian-11/

Comment: Ah, I see what my problem was. Even though I was on bullseye, I needed to use the buster release. And in response to Lexi Li, this is not my program I am trying to run, it's somebody else's.